# I am getting "Thread left active" and BundleID message.for HomeKit readValue

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I am using following function to update temperature value but every time I get value Xcode
logs that messages.

I tried it in a new project and an old project and got the same result.

**HomeKitTest[2150:1400742] [Activity] [-[HMCharacteristic readValueWithCompletionHandler:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/HomeKit/HomeKit-714.4.11/Sources/HomeKit/HMCharacteristic.m:513 (B6612D00-F307-476D-B35E-0CD8576C4767)] Thread left active (1): <NSThread: 0x283194640>{number = 1, name = (null)}**

**validateSessionInfo: bundleID is invalid. Please specify the bundleID for kRTCReportingSessionInfoClientBundleID**

```
func getTempValue(){  

    characteristics[0].readValue (completionHandler: { (error) in
        
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)  
        } else {
            self.writeValue()}
    })

 }
```

PS;

I stored characteristics in

```
     func homeManagerDidUpdateHomes(_ manager: HMHomeManager) { 
  }
```

according to my requests beforehand hence the **characteristics[0]**